# How to draw a half circle (border, outline only)

Tags: css

How to draw a stuff like this in CSS?

[image]

Comment: What are your constraints? Can we use `SVG`?

Comment: Wowzers. On hold after only a minute? Don't mess with mods…

Comment: Look at "magnifying glass" here. Wrap it in a div with overflow:hidden and move half of it off-screen. https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: @bjb568 "On hold" isn't some sort of penalty box -- it's really just a way to let the OP know they need to do some work to get the question re-opened. Once they do that work, the question is automatically kicked into the reopen queue. For an attentive question asker, there's nary a blip, and for everyone else, it makes for an answerable question.

Comment: @George I know that. Why do you need to suddenly start meta-rambling at us?

Comment: What's the problem with this question? Why do you ask if can you use SVG or not? The question is clear. "How to draw a stuff like this in CSS?" CSS. Not SVG.

Comment: I think "what have you tried?" is a standard comment for something like this. Providing a HTML or CSS snippted "template" to fill in would give context for answers.

Comment: As I'm still receiving penalties from this question, I'm really surprised by the "pro" side of this community. A guy with 30k+ reputation asks if he could use SVG, though the question clearly requires for CSS, and the same guy closes the topic because "it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem". If you reject to read the question, you are surely going to find yourself with the lack of sufficient information. Some questions are dead simple with dead simple answers, but some people will always need guidance beyond measure, mostly because they don't like to read.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<div style="
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
"></div>
```

http://jsbin.com/wedudine/1/